# Define macro twice in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

I'm working on embedded system project, and I don't know why I noticed this now, but if I define a variable twice the compiler doesn't give me any warning nor an error, which is very weird because I can accidently use the same name as another macro in the library which can easily send me to hell.

So what is the best practice to avoid, after thinking of it the only way is to test every name using #ifndef condition, but it the code will be very long and hard to read.

```
#define a 50 //defined in another library
#ifndef a // I check if 'a' already defined
#define a 10 // if not I can use that name
#endif
```

Think about doing this with hundred of macros, there must a better way which is directly related to the compiler.

Comment: Make sure you don't use names that are defined in other headers (macros are found in libraries).  If you must use the same name for your own purpose, forcibly `#undef` the macro and provide your own definition.  You don't want to use someone else's definition by accident.

Comment: `what is the best practice` `which is very weird because I can accidently` The best practice is to have unique macro names.

Comment: After repeated reading, your question becomes less clear... What do you ask for? Make the compiler warn you on duplicates? Best practice for unique names? Something else? Please clarify.

Comment: Since I discovered this kind of issue recently, I asked myself in the first time, if this is a normal problem or not, second, if it was a normal behavior then what people generally do to avoid typing the same macro twice.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler that conforms to the C standard must produce a diagnostic message if an identifier is redefined with different replacement text because the constraints section for macro replacement says, in C 2018 6.10.3 2:

> An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another `#define` preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical. Likewise, an identifier currently defined as a function-like macro…

If your compiler is not giving you such a warning, you should check for switches that improve its conformance to the C standard or that increase the warnings it produces. If there is no such switch, you should complain to the publisher of the compiler.

One way a failure to warn may arise is that some compilers have features for suppressing diagnostic messages while processing system headers. This is a reasonable behavior because system headers often need to do non-standard things that should be warned about (depending on circumstances) in user code but that may be considered intentional and proper design in system headers. However, it means that if you define a macro and then include a system header that also defines it (and differently), then the warning messages that would occur while processing the system header might be suppressed. To avoid that, include all system headers first, before you have any macro definitions.

For example, using GCC 12.2, this source code gets no warning:

```
#define EOF 4
#include <stdio.h>
```

but swapping the lines produces:

```
warning: "EOF" redefined
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i didn't get any warning and my IDE is based on Eclipse. I'll dig deeper later to figure out if there is something in the options.

Comment: @Vertinhol If you use a "managed" project in Eclipse, raise the compiler warnings to the maximum in the build settings (the default is `-Wall`). If you write your makefile or batch yourself, add appropriate options.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a big problem as you think , this is just a way is for safety purposes and not defining a micro twice but it's not a big deal because if you `#define` macro twice the compiler will give you a warning telling you that there is a redefinition of macro like in the image below :

[image]

, but you can force to delete the previous definition of the macro using `#undef` + <the_name_of_macro> , also there are naming conventions your macros like : don't use **_** at the start of your macro names because the macros beginning with underscore are C libraries specific , also it's more convenient to make your macro names all in capitals in order not to have a conflict with being misunderstood to be a variable not a macro and so on.

Comment: *if you `#define` macro twice the compiler will give you a warning* The question clearly states "but if I define a variable twice the compiler doesn't give me any warning nor an error"

Comment: As I said, I didn't get any warning.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least these measures you should take:

- Raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum.
- Apply a "no warnings, no errors" policy for your builds.
- Let the compiler look at warnings as errors. For GCC, this is the option `-Werror`.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the best practice

- use upper case for macros representing constants
- do not use macros
- limit scope of everything
- use unique names, typically with module prefix followed by `_`, like `#define LIB1_VALUE  something`.

> because I can accidently use the same name as another macro

Which suggests that your identifiers names are not unique enough. You should consider refactoring your code so that all identifiers are unique or limiting the scope of identifiers.

> Think about doing this with hundred of macros

Writing a program to generate such source code should be trivial, a map with a loop with 3 lines to print. Code generation is often used with C programs, you can use M4, Jinja2 or even PHP as a better preprocessor.

Comment: I cannot know what the developers of the microprocessor have already used in their library, and I'm not going to test every name every time I want t odefine something, also I can accidently don't pay enough attention and end upwith similar macros, which will drive me crazy later because something wrong happened.